# Синхронизация времени ноутбука на OC Windows 10 и смартфона на Android

Tags: android, windows, время, synchronized, ntp

ситуация у меня такая: на android я в в своих целях синхронизируюсь с ntp сервером через SNTPClient.java и получаю время, и записываю в файл. Потом подключился через wifi к ноутбуку и стал получать время с ntp с немного большей задержкой чем до этого. Поэтому, для лучших результатов, не подсказали установить время с ntp на ноутбуке и подключиться с android  к ноутбуку и получать время таким образом.По ссылке http://windows.mixed-spb.ru/domain/time_sync.php я настроил время по ntp. Но возникает сложность и недопонимание - как синхронизировать данные времени на ноутбуке и android. Теперь ведь android не берет время напрямую с ntp через такой код:

```
public class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return sntpClient.requestTime("1.ru.pool.ntp.org", 3000);
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {
                dateNow = new Date(sntpClient.getNtpTime());
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.SSS");
                sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03:00"));
                nowtime.setText(sdf.format(dateNow));
            }
        }
    }
```

Я пытался прописать вместо "1.ru.pool.ntp.org" IPv4-адрес ноутбука (192.168.65.103), который раздает wifi, чтобы таким образом брать теперь время с сервера - моего ноутбука, но не получается. Может я делаю что-то не так? Может эта функция и не случит этой цели, или кода вообще никакого не надо, чтобы синхронизировать время на устройствах? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Основная моя задача - подключить 3 смартфона к wifi и таким образом получать на каждом из них , надеюсь, одинаковое время.

Comment: Эммм... а штатные средства ОС не справляются?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какими штатными средствами это делается? я запутался совсем

Comment: Конкретно в аднройде - хз, но в Linux за это отвечает `ntpdate`, а в windows `net time`. Андройд по идее сам всё должен синкать более чем успешно, потому что это всё-таки ОС для встраиваемых систем. У тебя прям реальные проблемы, что 2 мабилы в твоей локалке рассинхрониваются больше, чем на пару секунд? А чё за задача такая, что время на столько важно?

Comment: Это учебная задача, сказали, что время может быть с разницей несколько миллисекунд (5-10). Задача локации: где ищется расположение объекта по звуковому эхо от него. Скорость звука большая, поэтому ошибка в определении местоположения будет больше с увеличением разницы хода времени на телефонах

Comment: IP ноутбука я исправил на 192.168.137.1 - так как ноут раздает wifi, то есть нужен его шлюз. Но еще я выяснил, что подключение к серверу длится слишком долго, и выходит за рамки таймаута. Еще тут в коде ````if (result)```` , где result = false. Поэтому в if программа не заходит.

Comment: Что с сервером не так видимо. Я устанавливал разные NTP серверы на ноутбук, но не работает этот код

Comment: Еще вот: если вместо ````result```` вставить результат функции                                                
   ````public boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            int timeoutMs = 1500;
            Socket sock = new Socket();
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.137.1", 8080);//53

            sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
            sock.close();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
    }```` , то результат равен true!  но время на телефоне возвращается в итоге такое 1970-01...